# PageSpeed Insights Mobile vs Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, pagespeed

I've come to the conclusion that PSI's mobile score is not affected by the time it takes to load every resource (onLoad event). On the other hand, PSI's desktop score is. Why is that?